# sed how to replace the regex string

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a string like
`"solrHost" : "http://localhost:8983,http://localhost:8764",`  in a file called sampple.json. 
There could be space between "solrHost" and : or maybe not, and there could be space between : and "http://localhost:8983,http://localhost:8764"

I have a another variable 
newServerName="http://newserver,http://newserver2"

**The value of solrHost could be anything between double quotes,**

I want to replace the value of solrHost from old to newServerName using sed can anyone help me here ?

Comment: Rule 1 of working with JSON: Use a tool that understands the format, like `jq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's%\("solrHost"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*\)"[^"]*"%\1"'"$newServerName"'"%'
```

- Use single quotes around most of the script.
- Use `%` instead of `/` to mark the sections of the `s///` (or `s%%%`) command.
- Use `[[:space:]]*` to cover zero or more characters in the space class.  Replace with just a blank-star if you don't care about the alternatives (tabs, etc), which is probably justifiable with well-formed JSON.
- Capture the original `"solrHost"` part.
- Be very careful with the quotes in the replacement.

  - `"'"$newServerName"'"`
  - The first double quote will appear in the replacement text.
  - The first single quote terminates the current single-quoted string.
  - The second double quote starts a new double-quoted string.
  - The replacement variable is next.
  - The third double quote ends the double-quoted string.
  - The second single quote starts a new (and rather short) single-quoted string.
  - The fourth double quote will appear in the replacement text.

Comment: That depends more on the layout of the fields.  The chances are it would be OK, but if the JSON is on a single line, the simpler code could replace the wrong info whereas the admittedly more complex code in the answer would not make that mistake.

Comment: You are correct and you would definitely need the alternative substitute delimiters, e.g. `sed '/^"solrHost"/s@"http.*$@'"$newServerName"'@'`

Answer (score 2):

You're much, much better off using a tool that understands JSON instead of trying to kludge together something with `sed` and regular expressions. [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is the go-to for command line manipulation of JSON:

```
$ cat foo.json
{
    "solrHost" : "http://localhost:8983,http://localhost:8764",
    "foo": 12
}
$ jq --arg url "http://newserver,http://newserver2" '.solrHost = $url' foo.json    
{
  "solrHost": "http://newserver,http://newserver2",
  "foo": 12
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I wonder if there's an answer as good as the classic ["Don't use regular expressions to parse XML"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) one for JSON...

Comment: I think that covers it. But you get some quirky questions that are not json, but sure look a lot like them. Either way with those quirky json-like formatted files, you are basically playing Russian-roulette without something like `jq` that is format aware and will validate the results.

Answer (score -1):

Use below sed command to replace the text .

```
%s/solrHost(old name)/newServerName/g
```